# Canvas animation / reactjs / with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I have multiple canvas animation on my app, everything is working smooth except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573529/reactjs-and-canvas-animation-requestanimationframe-not-smooth-on-iphone), but now I have a problem with animation Frame (my suspect).

When I load component(animation1) and then change to component(animation 2)and then get back to first component something weird is happened, animation is getting faster every time when I come back to that component and I don't know the reason.
Animation for both component is the same, moving objects up and down.

Strange thing is that on my console, moving speed is always the same even after 6-7 switches but objects are moving faster and faster every time...
Any idea what may be a problem?

Here is one animation, second is quite similar to this one:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
let loadBall = [];
let canvas;
let c;
let counterX = 40;
let counterY = 30;
let y =  counterY ;
class Loading extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            vy: 0,
            time:this.props.time
        }
        this.loadingLoop = this.loadingLoop.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        canvas = document.getElementById('ball');
        canvas.height = 150;
        canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
        c = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.loadingInit()
        this.loadingLoop()
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            canvas.width = window.innerHeight;
            this.loadingInit()
        })
        this.loadingInit();
    }
    loadingLoop(){
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loadingLoop);
        c.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (let i = 0; i < loadBall.length; i++) {
            loadBall[i].update();
        }
    }
    loadingInit(){
        loadBall = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let radius = 30//Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 15;
            let x =  (canvas.width / 2) - (radius * 4) + counterX;
            y = counterY;
            let color = colors[i];
            loadBall.push(new loadingBall(x,y, radius, color));
            counterY += 30;
            counterX += 70;
        }
    }
render() {
    return (
        <canvas id='ball' style={{position:'fixed', top: '50%', left: '50%',WebkitTransform:'translate(-50%, -50%)'}}></canvas>
    );
}
}

function loadingBall(x,y,radius,color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.move = 2
    this.update = () =>{
        if (this.y + this.radius + this.move >= canvas.height - 3) {
            this.move = -this.move    
        } 
        if (this.y - this.radius - this.move <= 3) {
            this.move = 2;
        }
        this.y += this.move;
        this.draw();
    }
    this.draw = () => {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 5);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
        c.strokeStyle = this.color;
        c.stroke();
        c.closePath();
    }
}
export default Loading;
```

Any suggestion can be helpful!

Comment: there doesn't appear to be anything that stops your render cycle (ie when the component unmounts). This will probably cause the existing render cycle to keep running in the background (while component unmounted), and then, when component is mounted again , spawn a second render cycle that causes two render cycles running in tandem which would explain what appears to be a "speed up" in your animation

Comment: I try to use componentWillUnmount and clear rect, empty array, cancel animation but nothing seem to work... how to stop animation when unmount component??

Comment: just added an answer below - hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is likely caused by your render loop (ie `this.loadingLoop`) not being stopped after your component is unmounted. As a result, when the component is unmounted the render loop continues to run and, when the component is mounted again, a new render loop is started - this causing two render loops running in tandem, causing the percived "speed up" in animation.

One way to address this would be to add a flag to your component that controls the continuation of the render loop. This could be achieved by adding the following:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        vy: 0,
        time:this.props.time
    }
    this.loadingLoop = this.loadingLoop.bind(this);

    // Add this flag to control if animation is allowed to continue
    this.stopAnimation = false;
}

componentDidMount(){

    // Add this to the start of componentDidMount to let animation 
    // start and continue while component is mounted
    this.stopAnimation = false;

    // ...
    // your existing code
    // ...
}

componentWillUnmount() {

    // When the component unmounts, set flag to stop animation
    this.stopAnimation = true;
}

loadingLoop(){

    // If the stopAnimation flag is not truthy, stop future
    // frames for this animation cycle
    if( this.stopAnimation ) {
       return
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(this.loadingLoop);

    c.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < loadBall.length; i++) {
        loadBall[i].update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)